# Random Char in 2D arrays

Tags: java, random, multidimensional-array

Hi i am new at java coding and am trying to create random numbers(which i have done) and i am trying to assign this random numbers as coordinates into the 2D array and print 'A' at the coordinates. Any help is appreciated.

```
package training;

import java.util.Random;

public class Training {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] values = new char[10][10];
        int foodX[] = new int[15];
        for (int i = 1; i < foodX.length + 1; i++) {
            int minFood = 0;
            int maxFood = 10;
            int randNum1 = minFood + (int) (Math.random() * (maxFood - minFood) + 1);
            int minFoodY = 0;
            int maxFoodY = 10;
            int randNum2 = minFoodY + (int) (Math.random() * (maxFoodY - minFoodY) + 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < foodX.length + 1; j++) {
                values[randNum1][randNum2] = 'A';

            }

        }

    // Assign three elements within it.
        // Loop over top-level arrays.
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            // Loop and display sub-arrays.
            char[] sub = values[i];

            for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
                System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i am new at java coding and am trying to create random numbers(which i have done) and i am trying to assign this random numbers as coordinates into the 2D array and print 'A' at the coordinates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Are you getting an exception? Different output than expected?

Comment: There are areaoutofbound error with my codes, and it does not print out 'A' @Mureinik

Comment: @Mureinik  
There are areaoutofbound error with my codes, and it does not print out 'A'

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are zero-indexed. What this means is that if you declare an array `myArray` as follows:

```
final int[] myArray = new int[10];
```

then you are creating a 10-element array which contains values in `myArray[0], myArray[1], ..., myArray[9]`. This also holds true for two-dimensional arrays, such as the `values` array in your code. However, you have defined `randNum1` and `randNum2` to return values in the range `1` to `10`. When either of those values is set to `10`, then `values[randNum1][randNum2]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you are trying to reference the array using indices that are out of its range.

In addition to this, you have created an array, `foodX`, which you do nothing with beyond determining its length. It's better in this case to declare an constant `int` value for this purpose. Finally, although you have imported the `java.util.Random` class, you are using `Math.random()` to generate random variables, which doesn't rely on this. You could alternatively use `Random.nextDouble()`, which would be useful if using a random number seed, but that's an aside.

Without following any additional considerations and to get your output simply to work as I believe is intended, I would therefore re-write your class in the following way:

```
package training;

public class Training {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[][] values = new char[10][10];
    int foodSize = 15
    for (int i = 1; i <= foodSize; i++) {
        int minFood = 0;
        int maxFood = 10;
        int randNum1 = minFood + (int) (Math.random() * (maxFood - minFood));
        int minFoodY = 0;
        int maxFoodY = 10;
        int randNum2 = minFoodY + (int) (Math.random() * (maxFoodY - minFoodY));

        values[randNum1][randNum2] = 'A';
        // I've removed the for loop in the line above since it simply does the same thing 15 times and is inefficient
    }

    // Assign three elements within it.
    // Loop over top-level arrays.
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        // Loop and display sub-arrays.
        char[] sub = values[i];

        for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

  }
}
```